# Elasticsearch query search with spelling mistakes

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search for **Kitchen applinces** in the search query, instead of that I have wrongly entered the name kitchen as kitchne **Kitchne applinces**, using of this query need to search for **Kitchen applinces** in the elasticsearch search query without fuzziness.

````
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "Kitchne applinces",
                        "fields": [
                            "title^3",
                            "keywords^2",
                            "description^1"
                        ],
                        "type": "phrase"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: Somehow, the wrong written terms need to be inside the inverted index. Or you need to use fuzzy. Do you have a specific reason not to use fuzzy here?

Comment: If yes, could you explain and give more example?

Comment: i want the exact match result, **Kitchen applinces**, matched with **Kitchen** or matched with **applinces** will be showing when am using fuzzy

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the slop to be able to find the results that you are expecting :

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Kitchne applinces",
      "fields": [
          "title^3",
          "keywords^2",
          "description^1"
      ],
      "slop": 0,
      "type": "phrase"
    }
  }
}
```

To find more information about slop you can check this page :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/slop.html